# Remove item from array result

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this result

```
 {
    "_index": "products-1479727033119",
    "_type": "product",
    "_id": "123",
    "_score": 5.2519913,
    "_source": {
      "name": "Samsung S7",
      "rating": 4.5123123,
      "id": "609126",
      "stores": [
        {
            "id" :123214,
            "name":"Walmart"
        },
        {
            "id" :2141251,
            "name":"ebay"
        }
      ],
    }
  }
```

In some cases, I need my result to be the same, however I need to filter the array items

And the result should be this:

```
{
    "_index": "products-1479727033119",
    "_type": "product",
    "_id": "123",
    "_score": 5.2519913,
    "_source": {
      "name": "Samsung S7",
      "rating": 4.5123123,
      "id": "609126",
      "stores": [
        {
            "id" :123214,
            "name":"Walmart"
        }
      ],
    }
  }
```

Is this possible in a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you have to look at nested objects in elasticsearch. You have to define mappings in your schema for nested objects. Once you setup your schema to support nested objects in your source document, you can use nested filters, innerhits.

Use the following schema mappings for your document.

```
-XPut "localhost:9200/products/product/_mapping"
    {
        "product": {
            "_source": {
                "enabled": true
            },
            "properties": {
                "stores": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "id": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "index": "analyzed"
                        },
                        "name": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "index": "analyzed"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "analyzed"
                },

                "rating": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now your usecase may or maynot include filtering the parent document, but since you essentially need to filter the nested documents to match some criteria, you can use nested filters/query with innerhits. Innerhits in elasticsearch return which inner nested document in the one document matched your nested query.

lets assume both cases-

a) Not filtering parent document -

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "nested": {
                            "path": "stores",
                            "query": {
                                "filtered": {
                                    "query": {
                                        "bool": {
                                            "must": [{
                                                "term": {
                                                    "stores.name": {
                                                        "value": "nokia"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "inner_hits":{}
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

b) filter both for parent and nested objects -

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {"term": {
                        "name": {
                          "value": "samsung"
                        }
                      }},
                      {
                        "nested": {
                            "path": "stores",
                            "query": {
                                "filtered": {
                                    "query": {
                                        "bool": {
                                            "must": [{
                                                "term": {
                                                    "stores.name": {
                                                        "value": "nokia"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "inner_hits":{}
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In case b, you can have a filter on the parent document as well.

Innerhits response -

```
   {
  "took": 6,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 2.122635,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "nested",
        "_type": "product",
        "_id": "AVmYrzR0isULrG9L5jlr",
        "_score": 2.122635,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Samsung S7",
          "rating": 4.5123123,
          "id": "609126",
          "stores": [
            {
              "id": 123214,
              "name": "Walmart"
            },
            {
              "id": 898989,
              "name": "nokia"
            },
            {
              "id": 67676,
              "name": "nokia"
            }
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits": {
          "stores": {
            "hits": {
              "total": 2,
              "max_score": 1.8472979,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "nested",
                  "_type": "product",
                  "_id": "AVmYrzR0isULrG9L5jlr",
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "stores",
                    "offset": 2
                  },
                  "_score": 1.8472979,
                  "_source": {
                    "id": 67676,
                    "name": "nokia"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index": "nested",
                  "_type": "product",
                  "_id": "AVmYrzR0isULrG9L5jlr",
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "stores",
                    "offset": 1
                  },
                  "_score": 1.8472979,
                  "_source": {
                    "id": 898989,
                    "name": "nokia"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see in the response object, the inner_hits comes out an additional json object along with source document, innerhits json object contains an array of all filtered nested document that matched "nokia" as name.

You do get what you asked form but in a different format/data structure. You can later write a API layer translator, model serializer to parse the response into proper format you wish your client(browser/app) require

Please refer [elastic innerhits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html) doc for more reference.

Hope this helps
Thanks